# MySQL server has gone away after Shutdown and Startup Server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench.  I shut down and restart my server.  After that I was not able to execute any queries as the error always come up immediately.

> Error 2006:MySQL server has gone away

I have started the MySQL57 services manually so I am sure the server is running.  Looking up SO, two solutions come up - (1) set `max_allowed_packet = 128M` in `my.ini` **[Failed]**, (2) set `wait_timeout` to a larger number - I cannot find the `my.cnf` file so this doesn't work.

What I encountered is pretty different from others as they usually had this error after a long piece of queries, but mine just comes up immediately after a query is sent. Appreciate any help (include finding the `my.cnf` file).

---

**Update:**
Discovered something that may help, what I have done:

1. Start MySQL57 from services.msc manually
2. Open MySQL Workbench, connect to database
3. Test the connection, and said "**Successfully made the MySQL Connection**"
4. Run a query, return "Error 2013: Cannot connect to MySQL Server on local host"
5. Run the query again, return "Error 2006: MySQL Server has gone away"
6. Check services.msc, the MySQL57 has been **switched off**.

Comment: Did you look at the MySQL error log?

Comment: @obe: What should I look for ? [This](https://justpaste.it/x2kh) is the error log generated by my latest shutdown/restart/startMySQL57.

Comment: Well I can't think of anything specific, it's just worth looking. I actually thought about monitoring the log while running the query that scares MySQL away :) but looking at the log you pasted, I noticed this: "[ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 3 in space 23, space name tickdata/tickdata, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.". Not sure what it means exactly or whether it's relevant but I suggest to check...